# How to read the dependencies from an eclipse .classpath in gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, classpath

here is a example of eclipse `.classpath` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-collections4-4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar"/>
   <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/kc-tools-thirdparty/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
   <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/main"/>
</classpath>
```

In gradle I would like to automatically add these into dependencies.

Is there any plugin which could do that ? (I know I could write my own method to parse XML but I am looking for some general way)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I highly suggest going the other way: always define dependencies in the Gradle build file, then import to Eclipse (either through the gradle-eclipse plugin or through Gradle Integration for Eclipse).

Comment: I have eclipse based project already running, gradle build is just a addition to existing ant. I wanted to avoid hardcoded libs strings therefore I was looking for some general solution, so gradle could get already setup classpaths from eclipse project .classpath file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't test it but I would do something like this:

```
//Init classpath file
def classpathFile = file('.classpath')
//parse xml
def cpXml = new XmlParser().parse(classpathFile)
//find all lib entries
def libPaths= []
cpXml.classpathentry.each {
    if('lib' == it.@kind) {
        libPaths.add(project.projectDir.parentFile.absolutePath + it.@path)
    }
}
dependencies{
    compile files(libPaths)
}
```

Comment: this inspired me, but you had there errors, I edited your comment

Comment: Ok. I think you forgot to rename mylibs into  libPaths. I changed it.